# How to quantify fairness of exams?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

So I was thinking about how to model exams. I assumed that teacher will give out $N$ problems to study. Due to the nature of exams, one can't have all $N$ problems on the actual exam, let's say teacher chooses m ($m \leq N$). Let's also assume that student can't study all $N$ problems and they only get through $r$ problems. What are possible overlaps and how are they distributed? Do you know of any problem similar to this that I can read up on (I couldn't come up with good phrasing to google this).

I went through a simpler version of this with $N=3, m=2, r=2$.

If lecture chooses $1$ and $2$ for exam.
A student might study

- $1$ and $2$ ($100\%$ overlap/score),
- $2$ and $3$ ($50\%$ overlap/score),
- $3$ and $1$ ($50\%$ overlap/score).

In most cases student gets $50\%$ of score, even though their body of knowledge is $66\%$.
I am trying to write out combinatorial equations, to understand this, but I wonder if this problem has been shown somewhere.

Comment: If you give an exam of two questions, the only possible scores are 0%, 50%, and 100%; I would say that 50% is most representative out of the three when it comes to an actual state of knowledge that is 66%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability distribution of the number of overlaps is the hypergeometric distribution, with probability distribution given by 
$$
P(\text{# overlaps $=k$})=\frac{\binom{r}{k}\binom{N-r}{M-k}}{\binom{N}{m}}.
$$
You mention fairness, and in your small example, you mention that even though the student studied $66.\overline{6}\%$ of the problems, most of the time they will know only $50\%$ of the questions on the test. Still, the average percent of quetions they will know is
$$
\frac13\cdot 100\% + \frac13 \cdot 50\%+\frac13 \cdot 50\%=66.\overline{6}\%,
$$
so the average proportion of questions on the test they will have studied is equal to the proportion of the total number of questions they studied. This is true in general; the expected propotion of questions the student will know is $r/N$.

Comment: In terms of perceived fairness, it may be better to look not at the mean, but at the variance.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm at easy since I know that my answer was right (proof that I'm not being dishonest https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a_qpv5PAcH6PpsXAz3xH5lUg3jkPns-U ). I liked the suggestion of variance as well. I'll try to read up on this on my own, But as I can see you're a teacher, and don't you see this as an inherent issue with testing? In my toy example nobody "gets what they deserve". Even in the general case a big chunk of "students" gets overestimated or underestimated.

Comment: @TeimurazSaghinadze If it is unreasonable for a student to able to study all $3$ questions, then you are right, I would call that unfair. I imagine this situation is unique to small $N$. If $N$ is large enough, then the unfairness (of which standard deviation relative to the mean is a good measure) will decrease.

Comment: @ Mike Earnest Sorry if I'm being annoying. $\frac{(N-m) (N - r)}{N(N-1)}$ is the quantity that you said (well based on Wikipedia). For clarity, if we define $\mu := m/N$ and $\rho := r/N$ (just to have some parts normalized), we'll get $\frac{(1-\mu) (1-\rho)}{(1-1/N)}$. "The Unjustice" coefficient increases as $1-\rho$ part that students didn't read/studied increases and as the teacher decides to exclude more parts a.k.a $1 -\mu$ increases. And bigger the N less significant it's denominator is. Hence the teacher has to make sure that their test is as exhaustive as possible. Am I getting it?

Comment: This seems right 300/200/200 30/20/20 and 3/2/2 should behave the same because each problem can be thought of accumulation of 10 or 100 subproblems. I know this isn't quite math, but if we take into consideration that student may not be willingly negligent and just forgot a couple of things from a rather big curriculum per see, burden falls on the teacher to make $\mu$ as close to 0 as possible.